# Cannot save FieldUserValue. Error: "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only."

Tags: javascript, data, read-only, person, spfielduser

this is my code:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var targetList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("reqLegales"); //my list
context.load(targetList);
var item = targetList.getItemById(obj.ID); //this id is ok.
var revisor = new SP.FieldUserValue();
revisor.set_lookupId($rootScope.loggedUser.Id);
item.set_item("revisor", revisor);
item.update();
```

There are more fields (site, location, asset, etc). If I remove the line "item.set_item("revisor", revisor);" works well.
I am using the same code to create the item in other field named "emisor" (emitter), but cannot update the record with this field (revisor). Both are person.

Comment: Is this field read only or multiple selection allowed for this field?

Comment: No, you can edit it directly in Sharepoint. It's not readonly and I'm the owner.